# Bagged Set Identification from 2011 - 3 bags somewhat separated into color themes (blue/green, white/brown, pink/yellow/orange)

Tags: set-identification

[image: Picture]
I managed to score some (partial) Lego sets still in the bags. All the bags are marked 2011, but I'm struggling to ID them after leafing through 24 pages of 2011 Lego sets on Brickset. The left bag has "135149" on it, but nothing in the search results seems to match the colors. The colors in the right and left bag, plus the flowers/florals, look like maybe they came from Lego Friends series? None of the Lego Friends sets I saw seemed to fit. The middle set I'm even more lost on. The arches, doors, and gray ribbed pieces make it seem like it could be part of a building set.

Comment: The year and number on the bag refer to the bag itself, not the set it was used for, so the only thing they can be used for is setting a lower bound on when the set was made (they can't have put parts in a bag that wasn't designed until later).

Answer (score 7):

Looks like [10692 Creative Bricks](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10692-1)

Justification addendum:

The first picture has a blue 2x10 plate. It's not that unique (113 sets on BrickLink). There's also a 6x12 plate which I initially thought was green, but it seems not to be, as no set on BrickLink has both those pieces. But if it's bright green, there are 3 matches. I can't at all be certain of the color of the 6x6 round plate by looking at it, but when I cross-reference BrickLink for sets that have

- at least 1 of Blue 2x10 plate
- at least 1 of Bright Green 6x12 plate
- at least 1 of 6x6 round plate with hole (in any color)

there is only this set.

[image: 10692]

Comment: Can you add some detail as to Why you think it is this set? That might be helpful to others learning how to identify sets from just bags.

Comment: @PhilB. The fact that the parts seem to be color-sorted into the 3 bags suggests this is not a set for building  a specific model, where the parts are usually bagged corresponding to the building sequence.

Comment: The inclusion of a brick separator seems unusual to me too, also hinting at a creative set rather than a specific model